# Android telnet client, reading stops after a few seconds

Tags: java, android, telnet, apache-commons

I am trying to implement a telnet client in android that is going to continuously read data from a telnet server. I have verified that the server is sending data continuously by connecting to it from a telnet app from play store.

Now im trying to create an app to do the same and display the data on the screen using apache telnetclient. I have successfully connected to the telnet server, and I am able to read the correct lines for 5-10 seconds. The code is posted below.

What works:

- Connecting to server.
- Reading some lines for 5-10 seconds before the stream stops.

The problem:

- The reading seems to stop after around 5-10 seconds, and hangs on readLine() with no new data coming in. Is this a problem with the code? Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to run this on an Android 4.2.2 device. I tried it on a newer android 7 device just now, and the code works as intended, I get continuous readings. Is there something in the android version that can be causing this?

--

**This is the TestTelnetClient.class**

```
public class TestTelnetClient extends Activity {

private TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
private InputStream in;
private PrintStream out;
private String server = "192.168.36.105";
TextView outputView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    outputView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
}


public void sendTelnet(View view) {

    TelnetRead telnetRead = new TelnetRead();
    telnetRead.execute();
}


private class TelnetRead extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            // Connect to the specified server
            telnet.connect(server, 8110);
            // Get input and output stream references

            in = telnet.getInputStream();
            //out = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String aad = r.readLine();
            while (true) {
                publishProgress(aad);
                aad = r.readLine();
            }
            //telnet.disconnect();
            //finish();
            //return aad;
            //return "exit";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            outputView.setText(result);
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.interrupted();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    //@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... result) {
        outputView.setText(result[0]);
    }
}
```

**This is the android manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".TestTelnetClient"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Where does it say that Telnet only sends lines?

Comment: By lines i mean that the product i am connecting to sends data on the format: "$PIXS,TIME_,xxxxxx.xxxxxx*xx", where x is numbers. Now for the first 5-10 seconds i get this as output from the readLine() function inside the while loop every 0.1 seconds approximately, and then it stops. I don't know if the Telnet protocol sends data in some way I have to account for with my code to get continuous reading. I don't have access to the source code for the server, but as I said, it works as expected when connecting with a telnet app from play store, where I get continuous reading from the server.

Comment: UPDATE:
I am trying to run this on an Android 4.2.2 device. I tried it on a newer android 7 device just now, and the code works as intended, I get continuous readings. Is there something in the android version that can be causing this?